# R Proble with Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo

How I could solve this exercise:

> Let U come from a uniform (0,1) distribution and Z come from a standard normal distribution. Let X = pZ + (1-p)U. Estimate p when X has a variance of 0.4.

Maybe I should install.packages('polynom')?

p is equal to 0,62 because I´ve already calculated it analitically, but I don´t know how to solve it with R using random random numbers generators

Comment: It is not standard question. It is needed to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

```
fobj <- function(p)  abs(var(p*rnorm(1e5) + (1-p)*runif(1e5))-0.4)
pval <- optimise(fobj,c(0,1))$minimum
```

where

- first define your objective function `fobj`, i.e., distance between variance of `X` and `0.4`
- then apply `optimise` minimize the `fobj`

**Result**

```
> pval
[1] 0.6223968
```

Answer (score 2):

I will not solve for you the exercice but give you the clue on how to solve it

You need to do as the exercice does:

1. Simulate U[0,1]
2. Simulate N(0,1)

Put them together using a value for *p*

For a given *p*, you can define a function:

```r
set.seed(234)
computeX <- function(p){

  u <- runif(1000)
  z <- rnorm(1000)

  X = p*z + (1-p)*u
  return(X)
}

var(computeX(0.2))
[1] 0.08924463
```

Now I let you find the routine to get *p* that is needed for your exercice.

No need for any external library

Comment: p is equal to 0,62 because I´ve already calculated it analitically, but I don´t know how to solve it with R using random random numbers generators